# How do I add CSS and JS to my Node localhost server with Express?

Tags: node.js, express, web-development-server

I was trying to get a simple webpage loaded, but it just shows the HTML skeleton and has two errors for CSS and JS in the console.

My code for `index.js` is below. I have tried using the static middleware for Express, but, still nothing. I have also tried asking for the CSS and JS file separately with `app.get`, but, it didn't accept it.

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("my-website"));
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    fs.readFile('./html/frontpage.html', 'utf8', (err, html) => {
        if(err){
            response.status(500).send('sorry, out of order')
        }
        response.send(html);
    })
})
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log('App available on http://localhost:3000'));
```

Comment: `app.use(express.static("my-website"));` is probably wrong if your serving `./html/frontpage.html`, why not just do `app.use(express.static("html"));` and get rid of the loading frontpage.html? Static can handle that https://glitch.com/edit/#!/cactus-tin-nautilus?path=server.js%3A9%3A0

Comment: As with all questions about serving static files, we need to see the exact HTML you're using in your page to reference the CSS and JS files.  And, we need to know exactly where those files are in your server file system relative to the index.js file.  Chances are you just have some of the paths wrong on one end or the other.

Comment: Please don't just post a question and then disappear for a long period of time.  It makes it really hard to help you.  Your question is missing detail that is required in order to help.  You aren't around to clarify.  Because of that your question has garnered some downvotes and close votes and may get closed as unclear.  When you post here, you should be checking back multiple times within the first hour to see if you need to clarify your question. If not, you miss the best opportunity for an answer when the most people see your question and your question may also get closed as unclear.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home - Aditya Thakur</title>
    <link  href="../css/fpstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../images/myFace.png">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>  
<body>
  
</body>
<footer>
    
</footer>  
<script src="../js/front-page.js"></script>  
</html>`

sorry for the late response. I had some personal family stuff going on for christmas.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let content = `  <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css"> // express automatically looks into the static path
  </head>
  <header> 
  <div class="header">
  <ul>
   <li>
<a href="https://webpage adress"> 
 
   </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </header>
  <body>
    <section>
    <div>
    <h2>My Course Goal</h2>
      <p>This api is set for </p>
    </div>       
    </section>   
   <script src="/script.js" ></script>  // 
  </body>
</html>`;

  res.send(`${content}`);
});
```

keep the styles.css and script.js files inside the static folder that you defined.

Answer (score 0):

In order our server, to serve up static files such as CSS and images, we need to use a special function of Express,and that is called static.So we need app.use(express.static()), and inside the parentheses add the name of a folder that will serve as our static folder,say "public" folder.
In public folder add folders as css,Images....etc.and add respective files like styles.css in css folder and in Images folder add img.png
[image]

If css file is not loading or if the error is -
"Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."
Add below code in JS file and HTML file respectively -

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){
  app.use(express.static("public"));
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
 })
```

In HTML--

```
<link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score -1):

To easily get what you want done, it will be better if you use a templating engine, something like pug(https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html), ejs(https://ejs.co/) or handlebars. They will help you set the headers plus they will allow you to easily integrate your css within files

Comment: Using a template engine doesn't have anything to do with properly serving CSS and JS files.